# Vue 3 Google Sign-In User Authentication shows deprecated warning in console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oauth-2.0, vuejs3, google-one-tap

I am trying to implement the Sign in using Google feature in my Vue 3 application, I found some npm packages to implement this feature, but these packages which are soon going to be deprecated ([This warning is shown in console](https://blenatem.sirv.com/console.png)).

I like to use [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web) for adding Sign in using Google feature to my web app which provides features like One-tap sign-up and Automatic sign-in, how can I easily implement this feature in Vue 3?

Comment: which type of grant types or flow do you use in google side ?

Comment: Previosly I was using Authorization code flow to obtain the Authorization from the popup then validate and get user basic data at backend, I am planning to do the same using the new  Google Identity Services also want to use the features like One-tap sign-up and Automatic sign-in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created a small plugin [vue3-google-login](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/) which uses [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web) to implement features like Sign In With Google, One-tap sign-up and Automatic sign-in.

Here is a sample code to create a simple Google Sign In Button using [vue3-google-login](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/)

First [initialise the plugin in main.js](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/#initialize-the-plugin) with your [Google API client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid)

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vue3GoogleLogin from 'vue3-google-login'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(vue3GoogleLogin, {
  clientId: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Then use GoogleLogin component like this

```js
<script setup>
const callback = (response) => {
  console.log("Handle the response", response)
}
</script>

<template>
  <GoogleLogin :callback="callback"/>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was really looking for this. This resolved my issue.

Comment: @Ananthakrishnan I went through your repo. How can I use this with vue 2 ?

Comment: @AnanthaKrishnan, i went through github repo for login, how to logout the user ?

Comment: @test_124 Sorry you may need to create this feature using custom code and  as the library was only targeting Vue 3  (Use  Google 3P Authorization JavaScript Library)

Comment: @sn1234 I think this will help you https://github.com/yobaji/vue3-google-login/issues/3

Comment: I am using the same code, but I also want to signin when the user clicks on GoogleLogin button. But this says JWT provided is invalid. How to solve this error. It working fine with One-tap sign-up and Automatic sign-in.